# Access value from multiple hierarchy stdclass in php

Tags: php, json

Given is $jdata taking data from other website. How to get time value from this json decoded data.

```
$jdata=json_decode($fdata);

//output of var_dump($jdata); given below

stdClass Object ( 
    [data] => stdClass Object (
                [date] => 2015-01-26 
                [hourly] => Array ( 
                                [0] => stdClass Object (
                                            [time] => 30 
                                            [WindGustKmph] => 21 
                                            [WindGustMiles] => 13 
                                            [windspeedKmph] => 12 
                                            )
                                )
                            )
                         )
```

How to access time value from the returned data?

Comment: You can $jdata=json_decode($fdata, 1); and then you get array instead stdClass. I think it will be more useful that stdClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jdata->data->hourly[0]
```

Should hold an object with the time data. For example:

```
$jdata->data->hourly[0]->time // 30
```

Comment: How to loop through the key, value?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $fdata->data->hourly[0]->time

Answer (score 1):

Try below to loop through :-

```
foreach($jdata->data->hourly as $k){
       echo $k->time;
}
```